# Julia: Array of ones: add one to zero or repeat?

Tags: julia

I have a concrete Array and want to efficiently construct a similar array of the same dimensions filled with ones. **What would be the recommended approach?**

Here's a random array to work with:

```
julia> A = rand(0:1, 10, 5)
10×5 Matrix{Int64}:
```

or `A = rand(0:1., 10, 5)` (with a dot on `0.` and/or `1.`) for a random matrix of floats.

Two approaches are very natural. I could do this:

```
julia> zero(A) .+ 1
5×10 Matrix{Int64}:
```

Or I could do it this way:

```
julia> repeat(ones(size(A)[2])', outer = size(A)[1])
5×10 Matrix{Float64}:
```

The first approach is more elegant. The second approach feels more clunky and prone to error (accidentally exchanging `[1]` and `[2]`), but at the same time it doesn't involve the addition operation and so possibly involves fewer allocations (or maybe not because the compiler is super smart **Edit: quick benchmark below suggests the compiler is super smart**).

And of course there may be another, better approach.

```
using BenchmarkTools
A = rand(0:1, 1000, 1000)

@btime zero(A) .+ 1
## 1.609 ms (6 allocations: 15.26 MiB)

@btime repeat(ones(size(A)[2])', outer = size(A)[1])
## 3.032 ms (10 allocations: 7.64 MiB)
```

**Edit 2: Follow-up onBogumił's answer**

The following method for a unit-array `J`, defined for convenience, is efficient:

```
function J(A::AbstractArray{T,N}) where {T,N}
    ones(T, size(A))
end
J(A)
@btime J(A)
## 789.929 μs (2 allocations: 7.63 MiB)
```

Comment: For a few minutes before reading the docs I thought `one(A)` would do for `1` what `zero(A)` does for `0`, but not so. No. `one` is instead an Identity array (different from `LinearAlgebra.I`).

Comment: Package `LinearAlgebra` does not seem to have a "unit matrix" (matrix of ones) similar to the identity matrix `I`. Not perhaps a huge need for it.

Comment: Not the core of your question, but in case you didn't know, it's much faster to do `rand((0, 1), N, N)` than `rand(0:1, N, N)`. You could also do `rand(Bool, N, N)` for ludicrous speed, or `Random.bitrand(N,N)` for plaid.

Comment: What you want is to apply `one` to each element, not to the array: `one.(A)`. This will also be generic to strange arrays (like StaticArrays, or GPU arrays, etc.)

Comment: @DNF, No I didn't know. And great to know, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
ones(Int, size(A))
```

or

```
fill(1, size(A))
```

Comment: Ah very nice! `801.155 μs (3 allocations: 7.63 MiB)` and `789.964 μs (3 allocations: 7.63 MiB)` on the examples above (see my edit made while you were answering). Thanks Bogumił!